# Androidの@PerActivityとは？

Tags: android

Androidのプログラミングで出てくる@PerActivityとはどういう風に使うのですか？

Answer (score 2):

@PerActivityはAndroidとして用意されているアノテーションではなくDagger2固有のアノテーションとなります。
Activityが生存している間のみ生存しているようにするように宣言するアノテーションになります。